# In Scala, how to use unapplySeq with pattern matching like List, start pattern and varargs parameters?

Tags: scala

Given this `RichFile` class and its companion object:

```
  class RichFile(filePath: String) {
    val file = new File(filePath)
  }
  object RichFile {
    def apply(filePath: String) = new RichFile(filePath)
    def unapply(rf: RichFile) = {
      if (rf == null || rf.file.getAbsolutePath().length() == 0)
        None
      else {
        val basename = rf.file.getName()
        val dirname = rf.file.getParent()
        val ei = basename.indexOf(".")
        if (ei >= 0) {
          Some((dirname, basename.substring(0, ei), basename.substring(ei + 1)))
        } else {
          Some((dirname, basename, ""))
        }
      }
    }
    def unapplySeq(rf: RichFile): Option[Seq[String]] = {
      val filePath = rf.file.getAbsolutePath()
      if (filePath.length() == 0)
        None
      else
        Some(filePath.split("/"))
    }
  }
```

Basically I want to extract all the components of a file path as a sequence. Why does wild-card match doesn't work in the following code? Specifically the first `case` statement I am getting the error `star patterns must correspond with varargs parameters`.

```
  val l = List(
    RichFile("/abc/def/name.txt"),
    RichFile("/home/cay/name.txt"),
    RichFile("/a/b/c/d/e"))

  l.foreach { f =>
    f match {
      case RichFile(_*) => println((x, y))
      case RichFile(a, b, c) => println((a, b, c))
    }
  }
```

I also want to match them just like we match Lists in Scala, something like this:

```
  l.foreach { f =>
    f match {
      case a::b::"def"::tail => println((a, tail))
      case RichFile(_*) => println((x, y))
      case RichFile(a, b, c) => println((a, b, c))
    }
  }
```

How can I do that using `unapplySeq`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the issue is just that you have both `unapply` and `unapplySeq`, so when you have just one argument in the `case RichFile`, scala is confused about which kind of unapply you are trying to do.  The way to resolve this would be to have two objects, one with `unapply` and one with `unapplySeq`, so that the usage is unambiguous.

```
class RichFile(filePath: String) {
  val file = new File(filePath)
  override def toString = f"RichFile($filePath)"
}

object RichFile {
  def apply(filePath: String) = new RichFile(filePath)
  def unapply(rf: RichFile) = {
    if (rf == null || rf.file.getAbsolutePath.isEmpty) None
    else {
      val basename = rf.file.getName
      val dirname = rf.file.getParent
      val (name, ext) = basename.split("\\.", 2) match {
        case Array(name, ext) => (name, ext)
        case Array(name) => (name, "")
      }
      Some((dirname, name, ext))
    }
  }
}

object RichFilePath {
  def unapplySeq(rf: RichFile): Option[Seq[String]] = {
    val filePath = rf.file.getAbsolutePath()
    if (filePath.isEmpty) None
    else Some(filePath.split("/"))
  }
}

val l = List(
  RichFile("/abc/def/name.txt"),
  RichFile("/home/cay/name.txt"),
  RichFile("/a/b/c/d/e"),
  RichFile("/y/z"))

l.foreach { f =>
  f match {
    case RichFilePath(a, b, c) => println("RichFilePath -> " + (a, b, c))
    case RichFile(f) => println("RichFile -> " + f)
  }
}
```

prints:

```
RichFile -> (/abc/def,name,txt)
RichFile -> (/home/cay,name,txt)
RichFile -> (/a/b/c/d,e,)
RichFilePath -> (,y,z)
```

---

Regarding the `::` syntax, you can't use `::` because it's already defined and only works on Lists.    Further, you wouldn't want `::` because operators ending in `:` are right-associative.  This makes sense for List matching because the item is on the left and the rest is on the right.  For your application, I assume that you want matching to read the same way as the directory structure: with the filename on the right and the "rest" on the left.  Thus, you can def define your own operator for this:

```
object --> {
  def unapply(rf: RichFile): Option[(RichFile, String)] = {
    if (rf.file.getAbsolutePath.isEmpty)
      None
    else {
      val f = rf.file.getAbsoluteFile
      Some((RichFile(f.getParent), f.getName))
    }
  }
}

l.foreach { f =>
  f match {
    case a --> b --> c => println(f"$a\t$b\t$c")
  }
}
```

prints

```
RichFile(/abc)  def name.txt
RichFile(/home) cay name.txt
RichFile(/a/b/c)    d   e
RichFile(/) y   z
```